# POST requests from Java don't reach PHP

Tags: java, php, post, request

I'm sending POST request `login=root&password=root` to `authenthication.php` by using `Authorize(String login, String password)` method from `AuthMediator`(which extends PHPMediator) in my Main class.

The problem is - my PHP script never receives anything(`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'`] is empty, but when I try to execute GET manually - it isn't). It worked(i.e. PHP was getting requests and processing them) when all the code was in one class(Main class) file. But after I've splitted it into different files, it stopped working.

Maybe there's some access modificators playing some funny tricks? I'm new to Java, and I'm still not fully understanding, which side effects they can have.

Here is my **authentication.php**:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password']) )
{
    $login=$_POST['login'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $userfile_path="../users/".$login;

    if(!file_exists($userfile_path))
    {
        echo "ERR_USER_INVALID";
    }
    else
    {
        $hash=md5($login.$password);

        $userfile=fopen($userfile_path,"r");
        if($userfile!=FALSE)
        {
            if(fgets($userfile)==$hash)
            {
                echo "OK_USER_VALID";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "ERR_USER_INVALID";
            }
            fclose($userfile);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "ERR_OPENING_USER_FAILED";
        }
    }

}
else
{
    echo "ERR_AUTH_MALFORMED_POST_REQUEST(".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] .")";
}

?>
```

**AuthMediator.class**:

```
package WebActivity;

import Constants.MagicConstants;

public class AuthMediator extends PHPMediator {

    public AuthMediator() throws Exception {
        super(MagicConstants.AUTH_URL);
    }

    public String Authorize(String login, String password) {
        String _data="login="+login+"&password="+password;
        try {
            this.sendData(_data);
            this.receiveData();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return "ERR_EXCEPTION";
        }

        return this._response;
    }
}
```

And it's parent **PHPMediator.class**:

```
package WebActivity;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;



public class PHPMediator {

    private URL _phpUrl;
    private URLConnection _urlConn;
    private OutputStreamWriter _outWrite;
    private BufferedReader _bufRead;
    protected String _response;


    PHPMediator(String url) throws Exception {
            this._response="";
            //opens connection
            this._phpUrl=new URL(url);
            this._urlConn=_phpUrl.openConnection();
            this._urlConn.setDoOutput(true);  

            //initializes writer and reader
            this._outWrite=new OutputStreamWriter(_urlConn.getOutputStream());
            this._bufRead=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_urlConn.getInputStream()));   
    }

    protected void setUrl(String url) throws Exception{
            //opens connection
            this._phpUrl=new URL(url);
            this._urlConn=_phpUrl.openConnection();
            this._urlConn.setDoOutput(true);  

            //initializes writer and reader
            this._outWrite=new OutputStreamWriter(_urlConn.getOutputStream());
            this._bufRead=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_urlConn.getInputStream()));     
    }

    protected void sendData(String data) throws IOException {
        String _data;
        _data=URLEncoder.encode(data, "UTF-8");
        this._outWrite.write(_data);
        this._outWrite.flush();


    }

    protected void receiveData() throws IOException {
        this._response+=this._bufRead.readLine();
        this._outWrite.close();
        this._bufRead.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should modify your  line String _data="login="+login+"&password="+password; As this means you are sending you infor using get Method. I dont know java but you can search and find how send data with post

Comment: Here you can find a well explained example of how to do post requests via java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the mistake.

```
this._bufRead=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_urlConn.getInputStream()));
```

has to be initialized after sending the message to server.

Answer (score 1):

POST requests do not generate a query string.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! But how can I get the list of all pairs "parameter"="value" for POST request in PHP?

Comment: look in the system array $_POST. 

    echo "<pre>";var_dump($_POST);echo"</pre>";

Comment: Also, if you are using firefox, or chrome use the developer debug tools to see what the actual ajax request is.